# Strange segfault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Ok, so I'm not really sure what is going on here.  I have a simple function, `int foo(char *filename)`, that takes `filename` and counts the words in a file.

```
int foo(char *filename){

  FILE *inFile;
  int wordCount = 0;    

  printf("foo\n"); // test printf() statement (currently prints)

  char word[50];
  inFile = (&filename, "r");

  printf("infile\n");  // test printf() statement (currently prints)

  while (1){
    printf("while");   // test printf() statement (doesn't print)
    fscanf(inFile, "%s", word);
    if (feof(inFile))
        break;
    printf("%d", wordCount); //test printf() statement
    wordCount++;
  }
  fclose(inFile);
  return wordCount;

}
```

As you can see, I print "infile", but not "while". I get a segmentation fault. Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work  Also, is my `inFile = (&filename, "r");` statement correct? I'm not that great with pointers.

Comment: Your `"while"` isn't printing because it's buffered, and your program crashes before the buffer is flushed. Change it to `"while\n"` and it should print too, even if your program still crashes.

Comment: This the second question I've seen in two days asking "What is up with this line of code: `this = (that, the, other)`?" I wonder if someone did a search-and-replace in a large codebase recently and accidentally all the function calls.

Comment: @ChrisLutz Accidently *what* all the function calls? :):):)

Comment: @littleadv He probably meant "accidentally _replaced_  all of the function calls". It's a shame that comments can only be edited within five minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm surprised this line actually compiles:

```
inFile = (&filename, "r");
```

If you're trying to open a file:

```
inFile = fopen(filename, "r");
```

EDIT:

And as mentioned, you need to end your `printf`s with `\n` or call `fflush(stdout)` or it will get buffered and not print.

Comment: That actually might compile perfectly fine. the result of the statement is the last operand, which can be silently casted (it's C...) into `FILE*`. Bummer....:-)

Comment: @Mystical: Not sure about C, but in C++ that expression would yeld a pointer to `filename` pointer. So if `FILE *` is defined as `void *` for example, that can compile. Otherwise type conversion failure should be triggered. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: Interesting... Another one of those corner-cases of C that I guess I haven't seen until now. :)

Comment: @littleadv - You can't silently cast `char *` to `FILE *`. You could silently cast `void *` to something, but not any other type (even if that type is explicitly compatible with `void *`).

Comment: @0A0D - it's obviously a typo in this case. However, I've seen people writing such a horrible code intentionally.

Comment: @VladLazarenko - even in C++, that expression would yield a `char*` pointing at `"r"`. The comma operator yields the right-hand operand, not the left-hand.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: What kind of obfuscation is this! I'd shoot the developer that made me figure that crap out ;)

Comment: @littleadv: Apparently. I have never seen such real-life use of the comma operator though. I'd consider that a candidate for the obfuscation contest.

Comment: In any event, this explains the seg fault. A bogus `FILE*` is handed to `fscanf`, and BOOM.

Comment: @ChrisLutz - you're correct, it should yield a warning, which the OP has probably ignored.

Comment: @0A0D - It's useful if you need a macro to perform several "statements" but also return a value, for example `#define dowith(f, a) (f(&a), a + 2)`.

Comment: @littleadv - I forget how low many people keep their default warnings.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: Good point. I was more thinking about @Vlad's wikipedia link.. Something like `int i = (a, b); // stores b into i`

Comment: @Mysticial - As an alternative to printing newlines (though newlines are always a good idea) you can call `fflush(stdout)` to flush the buffer manually. The buffer will also flush when the file is closed, usually when the program ends.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Yeah I use `fflush()` a lot when I have to print and erase a line repeatedly. (a status printer)

Comment: Oh, yeah, right-hand. Time for me to remember. Usually this stuff is not used for not good reason, and I saw it only in Boost where black magic is required.

Answer (score 4):

What are you expecting this line to do?

```
inFile = (&filename, "r");
```

Because it looks like you're missing a functional call.  I suspect you wanted something like this:

```
inFile = fopen(filename, "r");
```

That is, the `fopen` function expects a character pointer, and you have this:

```
int foo(char *filename){
```

So you don't need to use the `&` operator.  The `&` operator returns the address of a variable, so by entering `&filename` you're ending up with (a pointer to (a pointer to (char)).  You'll rarely use the `&` operator with strings; you'll usually see it used when a function needs to return multiple values (like the Unix `wait()` function).

There are a number of tutorials out there that talk about C pointers in more detail; a Google search for "c pointers" yields some likely results.  And of course, read your K&R :).

Comment: wow... why did I not see that. I'm embarrassed. I might want to open a file before I try to read it... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you don't see the "while" print is because it's not terminated with `\n`, thus is kept in the buffer and not printed out, by the time the seg fault occurs.

The seg fault occurs at `fscanf`, because you missed the `fopen`, and messed up your pointers. @Mystical explained how to fix it.

Comment: I didn't know that about the "while" print. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**ALWAYS** check the return value from `fopen()`, the call to which seems to be missing.

```
FILE *inFile = fopen(filename, "r");
if (inFile == 0)
    ...diagnose error...do not use inFile...
```

Note the absence of the `&` from `filename` in the call to `fopen()`; you simply don't need it.

The `printf()` before the `fscanf()` does not produce anything because the output string does not end with a newline; it is held over until you do print a newline, and the crash occurs before you do that.

The crash occurs because the string `"r"` is not a valid file stream; if you'd actually called `fopen()`, it would probably be because the open failed and you did not check it.

If your compiler did not give you warnings about the code, get a better compiler.  If it did give you warnings, learn to heed them (and fix them) before posting to StackOverflow.

---

While you're at it, you might want to consider what happens if the word you get to read is 50 characters or longer.  Happiness does not ensue.  You should consider using:

```
while (fscanf("%49s", word) == 1)
    wordCount++;
```

If a word is longer than 49 characters, it will at least now be split up into some number of 49-byte units (each counted as a word) without giving you buffer overflow problems (another source of crashes).  If you need a diagnostic print in the loop, so be it; add the braces and print.

I have very, very seldom had cause to use `feof()` in my (25+ year) programming career.  Code using it is generally suspect; I wonder if the person learned Pascal and hasn't unlearned it when learning C.

Comment: The OP may not need to get a better compiler - simply asking their existing compiler for more warnings may work.

Comment: It is rather appalling how much GCC lets you get away with without any warnings enabled. I think about 70% of GCC's warnings should be enabled by default, with flags to disable them (perhaps in groups, like `-noWall` or something) for the legacy code that needs it.

Comment: The GCC 4.2.1 and 4.6.1 compilers I have immediate access to both complain about `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type` with no options specified except `-c`.  If an older version (of GCC) does not warn, it is time to get a more recent version of GCC (a better compiler).  Granted, even an older version of GCC will complain if asked to do so (`-Wall`, etc), but better (newer) versions will complain automatically.